# Jquery UI tabs. Always shows previous selected tab index

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is my jquery code for getting current selected tab index. But, all of them return the previous tab values. I need current selected tab index. Please help

```
var selected = $("#enrichmentViewTabs").tabs("option", "selected");
                var sel2 = $("#enrichmentViewTabs").tabs().data("selected.tabs");
                var sel3 = $("#enrichmentViewTabs").tabs('option', 'active');
                var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)'),curTabID = curTab.prop("id");
                var sel4 = curTab.index();

                $("#enrichmentViewTabs").bind("tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
                        selected = ui.newTab.index();
                });
                alert(selected);
```

Comment: Are you accessing selected variable out of scope. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/TM6Lp/  coz your own code works and returns proper index/

Comment: like any array it begin from 0 to n so the tap1 will has index 0 and so on

Comment: @VishalVaishya Thanks so much for verifying it. Good to know this piece of code works fine. The problem must be in the way I wrote my html. Thanks again.